# How to unzip all files in a folder to their respective sub-folders using 7-zip on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, 7-zip, unzip

I see various posts/answers around this topic but the answers did not work.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- 64-bit
- 7-zip is located in c:\program files\7-Zip

I have a folder d:\zipfiles with many *.zip files

I want to unzip all zip files in this folder to their respective sub-folders

Answer (score 2):

This Windows command line works as of 2023:

```
for /r %f in (*.zip) do 7z x %f -o*
```

This assumes that the 7z.exe is available in your path.

If 7-zip is not in in your system path:

**Option 1:**

Replace 7z with the full path to the file "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" in the above code, like this:

```
for /r %f in (*.zip) do "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %f -o*
```

**Option 2:**

Edit the Windows "system environment variables", and add the 7-Zip folder to the list:

- click the Search icon (bottom left of taskbar)
- enter "edit the system environment variables"
- windows will open "System Properties"
- Click "Environment Variables" button (bottom right)
- Find the "Path" item in the top section, and click Edit...
- Check if 7-Zip is listed (most likely not), if not, click New button
- Enter where your Z-Zip app is installed (e.g. C:\Program Files\7-Zip)
- Click OK

Comment: Thank you! And for me, double quotes around the second %f because my path has some spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it via the GUI by selecting the *.zip files to extract, then right click -> 7-Zip (provided it is in the context menu) -> Extract files... -> then specify "*" in the following field (corresponding to the -o* command line option):

[image]